# The way pyglet swaps front and back buffers (`flip()`, wrapper for OpenGL's wglSwapLayerBuffers) on Windows can be 100 times too slow

Tags: python, opengl, window, pyglet, doublebuffered

Out of the blue (although I might have missed some automated update), the `flip()` method of pyglet on my P.C. became about 100 times slower (my script goes from about 20 to 0.2 FPS, and profiling shows that `flip()` is to blame).

I don't understand this fully but since my OS is windows 10, the method seems to just be a way to run the `wglSwapLayerBuffers` OpenGL double-buffering cycle in python. Everything else seems to have a normal speed, including programs that use OpenGL. This has happened before and fixed itself after a restart, so I didn't really look further into it at the time.

Now, restarting doesn't change anything. I updated my GPU driver, I tried disabling vsync, I looked for unrelated processes that might use a lot of memory and/or GPU memory. I re-installed the latest stable version of pyglet.

Now I have no idea how to even begin troubleshooting this...

Here's a minimal example that prints me 0.2s instead of 20s.

```
from pyglet.gl import *

def timing(dt):
    print(1/dt)

game_window = pyglet.window.Window(1,1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(timing, 1/20.0)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

(Within `pyglet.app.run()`, profiling shows me that it's the `flip()` method that takes basically all the time).

Edit: my real script, which displays frequently updated images using pyglet, causes no increase in GPU usage whatsoever (I also checked the effect of a random program (namely Minecraft) to make sure the GPU monitoring tool I use works, and it does cause an increase). I think this rules out the possibility that I somehow don't have enough computing power available due to some unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to solve my issue in this google groups conversation about a different problem with the same method: **https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/7yQ9viOu75Y** (the changes suggested in claudio canepa's reply, namely making `flip()` link to the GDI version of the same function instead of wglSwapLayerBuffers, brings things back to normal).

I'm still not sure why wglSwapLayerBuffers behaved so oddly in my case. I guess problems like mine are part of the reason why the GDI version is "recommended". However understanding why my problem is even possible would still be nice, if someone gets what's going on... And having to meddle with a relatively reliable and respected library just to perform one of its most basic tasks feels really, really dirty, there must be a more sensible solution.